# CSS3 Multiple backgrounds with linear gradient gives error in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, background-image

Who's got a clue what's wrong with the following CSS statement? Chrome (22) and Safari (on Windows) throw the error "Invalid property value".

```
background-image: url("../img/radio_default.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 40%, #ececec);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because it doesn't implement `to bottom` yet, you have to use just `top` or `bottom` instead.

edit: as pointed out in the comments, `top` corresponds `to bottom`

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 40%, #ececec);
```

Comment: `to bottom` actually corresponds to `top`... oddly enough.

Comment: Whoops, my fault, you're right. The value specifies where to start the gradient, where as the current W3C spec variant `to *` specifies the direction, feels odd, but that's what happens when working with not yet standardized techniques :)

Comment: It looks like they've changed the origin direction as well, so the same angular values (degrees, radians) have different results too, at least between the spec and in browsers. So that makes two heavily-changed modules I'm aware of: Flexbox and Image Values. Thankfully, both are CR now!